# Get user's position in a leaderboard?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm making this game leaderboard and I am trying to get a specific user's position in this leaderboard. I have tried this but with no luck:

```
SELECT SUM(points) as points 
FROM publicpoints 
GROUP BY fk_player_id 
WHERE points > (SELECT SUM(points) as points 
                FROM publicpoints 
                WHERE fk_player_id = $playerid)
```

How should I go about this?

---------------- EDIT -----------------

I have also tried like this, but still no luck but maybe this claryfies what I try to accomplish:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(points) mypoints FROM ".$prefix."_publicpoints WHERE fk_player_id=$playerid");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

$mypoints = $row['mypoints'];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(points) as points FROM ".$prefix."_publicpoints 
                        WHERE points < $mypoints
                    GROUP BY fk_player_id");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

$rank = mysql_num_rows($sql);

if(!empty($mypoints)){
    $rank = $row['rank']+1;
} else {
    $rank = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WHERE` clause must be before the `GROUP BY` clause like so:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(points) as points 
FROM publicpoints 
WHERE fk_player_id = $playerid
GROUP BY fk_player_id;
```

Then you can use the `ORDER BY` with `LIMIT` to get a specific `Points` position:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(points) as points 
FROM publicpoints 
WHERE fk_player_id = $playerid
GROUP BY fk_player_id
ORDER BY points
LIMIT 1 -- for top 1;
```

---

**Update:** To get how many users who has higher points than the current user, you can do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumberOfPlayers
FROM
(
    SELECT 
       fk_player_id
    FROM points 
    GROUP BY fk_player_id
    HAVING SUM(points) > (SELECT SUM(points)
                          FROM points 
                          WHERE fk_player_id = 5)
) t;
```

If you want to get those players that has higher points than the current user, you can do this:

```
SELECT 
   fk_player_id
FROM points 
GROUP BY fk_player_id
HAVING SUM(points) > (SELECT SUM(points)
                      FROM points 
                      WHERE fk_player_id = 5);
```

### [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/09050/15)

Comment: @ArunKillu Actually I didn't understand what this subquery for. But yes, you can use the `HAVING` clause to limit the total points comes from the `SUM(POINT)` like `HAVING SUM(POINTS) > (SELECT ...)`

Comment: In my DB table I have alot of records with different fk_player_id's. I want to be able to SUM up the points for each user and create a leaderboard. This I have done without any problems, but... I also want another place at my page to tell the specific placement on the leaderboard for the current player. Thats why i had the subquery!

Comment: @JesperMansa - So you are looking for something like pagination? To get only n results from the query?

Comment: Nope, no pagination. Actually I am interested to figure out how many users who has higher points than the current user. See edited post above.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal OK, super, but one last question. Is it possible to get the users points out of the query to use with echo or print from your second solution? If yes... How? I have tried with as mypoints but with no luck!?!